# Generate a random number in a specific range

Tags: java, random

I am making a program that will generate a random number from 1 to 10 in main and store it in specific fields but we are instructed to use Random.java. What codes shall I put in Random.java ?

Comment: You know, you can google things like that easily. This is a useless question, since you didn't even try to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

you can [try](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) this

```
Random random = new Random();
int i = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

this will genrate random `integer` number between 1 to 10

Comment: NB. if you pass a value to `Random()` you can get the same results repeatedly which can help testing.

Comment: you mean new Random(10)

Comment: It doesn't have to be 10 but yes, something like that.

Comment: try what u r saying with any number. I don't think you will get the appropriate result.

Comment: I get exactly what I imagined. What do you think you get?

Comment: i get a long value not integer between 1 to 10

Comment: Paste the code you're using here. The argument you pass to the `Random` constructor makes no difference to the scale of the numbers generated. [Random Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long))

Comment: i'm only passing 10 to constructor not to nextInt() thats why i'm getting the long vale . Now i got your point and getting the same value. But if you want this type of result for testing you can easily hard code the value why use Random.

Comment: Generally if you want a long sequence of 'random' numbers or if you want a new number for each iteration of a loop. Passing a seed will make that sequence repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();

int  n = rand.nextInt(k) + 1;
```

k is the range you want and it is exclusive so you'll have to add the +1